# Hide Email in MySites

Tags: my-site, mysites

We currently have the work email displaying on the MySites page - is there a way to hide this for a group of people?

We have a group of doctors who do not want their email shared.

Answer (score 1):

If your site has jQuery a simple solution without changing your setup would be:

`$('div#ProfileViewer_ValueEmail').remove();`

You can add this to person.aspx on page load.

Answer (score 0):

This is better... SharePoint 2010:

> First we want to go into Central Administration –> Application Management –> Manage Service  Applications –> Select your User Profile Service Application and then click manage in the ribbon. Under People select manage user properties. Then scroll down and find the Status Message property, pull the drop down and select edit. In the edit property screen this is where we will change the settings to not show or allow editing as seen in the screenshot below.

The setting you are looking for is.

> Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page

UPDATE:

This article has screen shots explaining how to do the above but in SharePoint 2013:
http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/224/SharePoint-2013-user-profiles-%E2%80%93-Add-custom-properties

Comment: Deleting the email property would have dramatic consequences for the farm, not the least of which would be the loss of all email-based functionality like alerts and many workflow steps.

Comment: Wouldn't following this step only remove the Email from the User Profile? I always had thought that when SP sends out notification emails the email address comes from the AD

Comment: SharePoint syncs the email from AD into the user profile in a batch operation that usually runs nightly.  SharePoint actions/emails only use the information in the user profile.

Comment: Yes, the AD sync, the User Profile Service, but the email for notifications comes from the User Information List not the MySites.

Answer (score 0):

I have not customized a MySite page so this is just a shot in the dark, but why not add another property to the UserProfile called something like "HideEmailAddress" and set it to True for your group of doctors.  You could then modify the XSL on the mysite page to not display the email address if this property is true.